# how to remove carriage return from remote linux file using paramiko

Tags: python, paramiko

My python code which is running on windows m/c and i am trying to remove carriage return (\r) in a remote Linux file using paramiko..none is working:

```
ssh_conn.exec_command("sed -i 's/\\r$//g' {location}/filename.txt;")
ssh_conn.exec_command("sed -i 's/\r$//g' {location}/filename.txt;")
```

The below command works fine on linux m/c.

```
sed -i 's/\r$//g'{location}/filename.txt
```

I tried placing \\r instead of \r in the command in the code assuming that \r might be taken as carriage return on window, see below:

```
location = '/test'
print(f"sed -i 's/\r$//g' {location}/filename.txt;")
print(f"sed -i 's/\\r$//g' {location}/filename.txt;")
```

output:

```
$//g' /test/filename.txt;        #incorrect command ..makes sense why not working.
sed -i 's/\r$//g' /test/filename.txt; # correct command ..does not makes sense why not work
```

Comment: nope ..if i run below query on linux it remove carriage return : sed -i 's/\r$//g'{location}/filename.txt .....i was wonding why it is not working when i run the same command from remote windows m/c using paramiko

Comment: Thanks for input, I updated my question.

Comment: Notice how you aren't using an f-string when calling paramiko? Without the `f` before the `"`, `{location}` doesn't get replaced with an actual value.

Comment: But your immediate problem is the `\r`.

Comment: Well, that, _and_ the failure to use a f-string.

Comment: ...honestly, I'm tempted to call this close-as-typo. You already _know_ how to use an f-string -- you're using them in other code -- and you also know that there's supposed to be a space before the `location`, but just made a mistake in the `exec_command()` call.

Comment: To be clear, `$//g'/test/filename.txt;` is just printed without the other content _because of the literal carriage return making the cursor go back to the front of the line and overwrite other content during printing_. The command itself is fine -- the other content is there in the string -- it's just how it's printed because the CR tells the cursor to go to the left.

Comment: And `sed -e 'command'filename` never works and has never worked. You **must** have a space between `'command'` and `filename`.

Comment: i am sorry the space is there ...let me correct the quesiton

Comment: The other complicating factor is that `sed -i` is not a POSIX-standardized feature, so it's not guaranteed to even be there at all, nor to have any particular behavior, unless you know which operating system the host you're SSH'ing into is running. (On BSDs, for example, `-i` has a mandatory option-argument of an extension to backup the original file with, and it behaves in surprising ways when not provided such an extension).

Answer (score 1):

When you type `\r` at the Linux command line in a single-quoted string context, it's two characters -- a backslash, and an `r`. That's what your `sed` line expects.

When you type `\r` inside a Python double-quoted string, it's *one* character, a literal carriage return (which sends the cursor back to the front of the line when it's printed, hence hiding everything before that point in output).

Either make it `\\r` in the Python code or use a *raw* string.

To demonstrate:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> len('\r')
1
>>> len(r'\r')
2
```

So, to fix this:

```
ssh_conn.exec_command(rf"sed -i 's/\r$//g' {location}/filename.txt;")
```

- The `r` prefix makes it a *raw* string so backslashes are literal.
- The `f` prefix makes format-string sequences be honored.
- The space between the sed command and `location` ensures that these are two separate arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer ..let me try it